# CKR_DEVICE_ERROR using iaik for digital signature

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#11, iaik-jce

I'm try to develop a Java Application that is able to do the digital signature on a file with smart card.

I set the PKCS#11 provider in this way:

```
Security.addProvider(new IAIK());
Properties providerProperties = new Properties();
providerProperties.put("PKCS11_NATIVE_MODULE","path\\asepkcs.dll");
IAIKPkcs11 pkcs11Provider = new IAIKPkcs11(providerProperties);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
 Module module = Module.getInstance("path\\asepkcs.dll");
```

After I read the KeyStore that I load in to smart card before, but when I try to use the method for create the digital sign the application catch the follow exception:

```
java.security.SignatureException: iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DEVICE_ERROR                      
at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.provider.signatures.ExternalHashSignature.pkcs11Sign(ExternalHashSignature.java:294)
at iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.provider.signatures.PKCS11Signature.engineSign(PKCS11Signature.java:638)
at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineSign(Unknown Source)
at java.security.Signature.sign(Unknown Source)
at sii.tesi.firma.provasc.FirmaScK.main(FirmaScK.java:288)
```

I'm not be able to understand how I could resolve the CKR_DEVICE_ERROR.
I use for the sign the follow methods:

```
Signature signAlg = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA"); 
signAlg.initSign(privateKey); 
signAlg.update(toBeEncrypted); 
byte[] signatureValue = signAlg.sign();
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed CKR_DEVICE_ERROR. The problem was simply that the smartcard was making a bad connection (Omnikey 6121 are badly build)

a paperclip to jam the chip tighter on the board fixed this problem for me.

Comment: Yes, same happened to me

Answer (score 0):

DId you use the Pkcs11Wrapper as well? If so, did you specify the `java.library.path`? The Wrapper version should match the Provider version, or check the readme for more details.

Regarding your code, specify the IAIK provider:

```
Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", iaikProvider)
```

and try to add the provider like this:

```
IAIK.addAsProvider(false);
```

If that doesn't help check the error log generated by the pkcs11 module.